# Jumping layout in UIPageViewController with UICollectionView in embedded controllers

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I work on the app that has an UIViewController with UICollectionView, embedded in a UIPageViewController.

[image]

The app supports both portrait and landscape orientations. It has a layout issue on swiping pages and changing orientations. **The cell is changing it's frame while user swiping pages**.

Video with the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/melxu8mlo2m6xrw/Video.mov?dl=0

PageViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

/// Subclass of UIPageViewController
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self
        
        let controller = createController()
        setViewControllers([controller], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource
extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return createController()
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return createController()
    }
    
    /// Create a new PostViewController from storyboard
    func createController() -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PostViewController") as! PostViewController

        return controller
    }
}
```

PostViewController.swift:

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let color = UIColor.random
    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup initial layout configuration
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = (traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact) ? .horizontal : .vertical
        }
        
        // Register cell
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // CollectionView's background color
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    }
    
    /// Switch scroll direction on rotation
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            if (size.width > size.height) {
                layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            } else {
                layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension PostViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color
        return cell
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension PostViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    /// Size of safe area of UICollectionView
    var collectionViewSafeSize: CGSize {
        let safeAreaInsets = collectionView.safeAreaInsets
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width - safeAreaInsets.left - safeAreaInsets.right
        let height = collectionView.bounds.height - safeAreaInsets.top - safeAreaInsets.bottom
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            if collectionView.bounds.width < collectionView.bounds.height {
                // portrait
                let safeSize = collectionViewSafeSize
                return CGSize(width: safeSize.width, height: safeSize.width)
            } else {
                // landscape
                let safeSize = collectionViewSafeSize
                return CGSize(width: safeSize.height, height: safeSize.height)
            }
        default:
            return .zero
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have ideas on how to set it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try **`screenBounds.width < screenBounds.height`**
instead of **`collectionView.bounds.width < collectionView.bounds.height`** in
**sizeForItemAt**

or

you can use **`UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape`** to find the orientation

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it doesn't work with screen bounds too.